# Given number n find the sum of the even positive numbers before it

Tags: c++

here given the number 'n' we have find the sum of the even positive numbers before it. For that I tried to put a while loop in a for loop,but looks like that wont work

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int sum=0;
    for(int counter=1;counter<=n;counter++)
        while(counter%2==0) {
            sum=sum+counter;
        }    
    cout<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: "_but looks like that wont work_": Please give full detailed explanations when asking questions. How does not work? Does it produce an error? Does it output the wrong result? For which input and which result did you expect? Etc. See [mre] and [ask]. Run your program in a debugger, which allows you to step through each instruction, watch the values of your variables and thereby observe where your program logic is flawed.

Comment: [The Song that Never Ends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz6OGVCdov8)

Comment: This can be calculated directly, without a loop. Hint: the sum of the integers 1..N is N(N+1)/2.

Comment: Do you expect any number `even + 1` to also be even? You do realize that you can use `counter += 2` in the loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
for(int counter=1;counter<=n;counter++)
    if(counter%2==0) // this is an if condition, not another loop
    {
        sum=sum+counter;
    }
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but should we *really* be answering questions like this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd highly recommend incorporating some sort of UI, as it'll help you keep track of what's going on as your programs grow in complexity:

```
    cout << "Enter an integer, and I will calculate the sum of all its  preceding, positive integers: ";
```

And you'd need to swap that "while" for an "if". Reason being, you're adding to the sum, *IF* the counter's value is even:

```
for(int counter=1; counter<=n; counter++){
   if(counter%2==0){
    sum=sum+counter;
   }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over numbers, we can solve this in `O(1) time complexity`.
Notice that sum of even numbers before a number N, forms an [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) with 2 as first term, common difference 2 and number of terms ⌊N/2⌋

```
Sum = 2 + 4 + 6 ... N
Sum = 2(1 + 2 + 3 ... N/2)  
Sum = 2((n)*(n+1)/2)   
Sum = n*(n+1)
```

where n = ⌊N/2⌋

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    int N
    cin>>N;
    N = max(0, N);
    
    long n = N/2;
    
    long sum = n*(n+1);
    
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```